# How to expose sub module function, from a module

Tags: powershell

How do you expose a function and an alias from a module, from a sub module

`profile.ps1`:

```
Import-Module module_one.psm1
```

`module_one.psm1`:

```
Import-Module module_two.psm1:
```

`module_two.psm1`:

```
Set-Alias readme -Value "Read-Me"
function Read-Me() {
    Write-Host "Hello..."
}
Export-ModuleMember -Function Read-Me, readme
```

I want to be able to call this function from the pwsh terminal, function name or alias?

I get (`readme` or `Read-Me`):

```
Read-Me : The term 'Read-Me' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ co
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (co:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Note: it works for functions in `module_one.psm1`.

Comment: Use the `-Global` parameter on the `Import-Module` commands?

Comment: Thanks, totally works for functions. Do you know, should I just keep aliases at the module_one.psm1 level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you call `Import-Module module_one.psm1` and later `readme` / `Read-Me` in the same scope domain (either outside a module or from the same (other) module), your code works in principle:

**The exported elements of the indirectly imported module are (also) imported into the top scope of the caller's scope domain.**

**Your problem is that you're trying to export *alias* `readme` as a *function***; you need to **use the separate 
`-Alias` parameter** instead:

```
Export-ModuleMember -Function Read-Me -Alias readme # Note the -Alias parameter
```

Also note that in the *absence* of an `Export-ModuleMember` call it is *all* (top-level) functions and aliases (but not *variables*) that are exported *by default*, so in your particular case simply omitting the call would have fixed the problem too.

In general, though, it is **better to be explicit about what elements are exported, and that is best done via a full-fledged module** that is not just a single `*.psm1` file, but an entire *directory* named for the module, housing the `*.psm1` file with an associated *module manifest*, which is a `*.psd1` file that describes the module, notably also in terms of its exports.
If such a module is placed in one of the directories listed in `$env:PSModulePath`, its exported commands can be discovered (e.g., with `Get-Command` or tab-completion) even before the module is imported, via a feature called *auto-loading* - see [about_Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules).

---

Note that **`Import-Module -Global` is rarely needed and should generally be avoided**, because it makes a module's exported elements available to all loaded modules too, which can have unintended side effects (modules should declare their dependencies explicitly).